# Printing List values

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to print all data in the List with the following code but nothing get printed. what is the correct way of doing it? I can display the contents in a JSP page by using foreach loop.

```
List report = new ArrayList();
report = SQLHelper.report(Id, startDate, endDate);

for (int i = 0; i < report.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(report.get(i));
}
```

Comment: what is the size of report, try to check

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` prints on console not on jsp itself.

Use `out.print()` instead.

Comment: Even not printed on the console.

Comment: try out.print() to print on jsp page.

Comment: @HafsaAbdulgafoor It is means list is empty.